# Why is decimal.Parse() slower than (decimal)double.Parse()?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

Why is it faster to parse with `double.Parse()` and cast to `decimal` rather than calling `decimal.Parse()`?

Given the following;

```
string stringNumber = "18.34";

double dResult = 0d;
decimal mResult = 0m;
for (int i = 0; i < 9999999; i++)
{
    mResult = (decimal)double.Parse(stringNumber);
    mResult = decimal.Parse(stringNumber);
}
```

Results in the following metrics in VS2017 profiler (.NET framework v4.7);
[image: Performance metrics]

The cumulative `double.Parse()` and cast comes to 37.84% of the CPU usage vs `decimal.Parse()`'s 46.93% of the CPU. There is more of a difference there than can be easily put down to a difference in datatype size. Can anyone explain?

The app where this came up on the profiler takes 10+ days to run so this small difference equates to hours of runtime. It'd be good to understand why. I can see that `decimal.Parse()` calls out to `oleaut32.dll` but...wth?

Comment: Converting between `float`/`double` and `decimal` is not a very good idea

Comment: Note that `decimal` will represent a decimal number exactly to a given precision where as `double` does not for all decimal values.  Thus parsing to `double` then casting to `decimal` may give different results.

Comment: @juharr, different, sure but why slower? I'd have expected it to be a little faster if anything...

Comment: So, you think that ensuring the precision of 10 numbers should be faster than of 2? (example numbers, of course)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I'm going to naively say "yes"? Surely fixed precision is an easier operation than working out a floating point one?

Comment: Why would it be faster, you are dealing with 128 bits of data instead of 64 bits of data. It no-longer fits within a single CPU register so I would expect it to be slower. Also, the parsing algorithms for the strings are completely different, in different dlls even, maybe double is more optimized?

Comment: @DiskJunky `decimal` is not fixed precision. It's floating point too, it's just decimal floating point rather than binary floating point.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, that'd make some kind of sense but it's a bit unexpected why the `decimal.Parse` would be less optimized than `double.Parse()` if so

Comment: Because decimal is used a lot less frequently so less time has been put in to it. decimal is a niche type, mainly only only frequently used for representing money. 99% of floating point math a computer needs to do is not working with money and does not need the 128 bits so they spend 1% of their time optimizing decimal compared to the 99% of the relative time optimizing other floating point types.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain a reasonable hypothesis but there are many applications out there dealing with money values. EF even equates SQL's `money` type to `decimal`. It's used quite a bit, if anything - though, you're right, not near as much as `double`. Still, it'd be nice to get at the source to see what's going on in there

Comment: So, the remaining question is, do you actually *need* decimal in your application? And why are you parsing so much?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto not too relevant to the question but probably not. Legacy code and very calculation intensive. Now `decimal` is littered through the code base so it's not going to be too easy to take it out given that the results genuinely do need some level of precision. It's uncertain how much.

Comment: @DiskJunky, ok... [doubles' implemtation](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/6cee3ea2010cf754c8f4667bfbc75e06b1f06159/src/classlibnative/bcltype/number.cpp#L403-L417), [decimal's implmentation](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/63f1a0f6fbb0f24dc881be1defa899eae9dbf86c/src/classlibnative/bcltype/decimal.cpp#L291-L364)

Comment: It is not clear how running the exact same operation `9999999` times is representative of what your application does, that's why I asked. `double` has 15/16 digit precision, `decimal` has 128.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, the app maxes out the CPU for 10+ days while it loads data performs calculations on large matrices of data. There are a few `decimal.Parses()` which appear fairly high up on the profiler (about 5th/6th) as most expensive operations. Changing to `(decimal)double.Parse()` reduced overall workload by 2%. The sample code there was to max out the CPU doing both operations to highlight the difference

Comment: @ScottChamberlain excellent response as always :) So the answer seems to be that the `decimal.Parse()` deals with the precision in situ where as the `double.Parse()` is optimized to do as work in integers as much as possible. You called it! if  you want to post that as an answer, I'm happy to mark it as such!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going from the source of [double's implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/6cee3ea2010cf754c8f4667bfbc75e06b1f06159/src/classlibnative/bcltype/number.cpp#L703-L835) and [decimal's implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/63f1a0f6fbb0f24dc881be1defa899eae9dbf86c/src/classlibnative/bcltype/decimal.cpp#L291-L364) it appears that the `decimal.Parse()` deals with the precision in situ, whereas the `double.Parse()` is optimized to do as much work in integers as possible.